# Reuse webviews UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uiwebview, uicollectionview, wkwebview

I have a collection of cells inside a UICollectionView. Each of the cells contains a WebView which is shown in a particular state. When the 'add' button is pressed, a new cell embedded with a WebView is added to the UICollectionView. This results in some cells being reused and the WebView not longer restricted to its previous cell. I am performing a reload on every 'func collectionView' to reload any web address and make sure that each cell is reusable.

The problem is that the WebViews take sometime to reload and it looks a bit ugly having WebViews being reloaded only due to Cell reuse. What's the best way to go around this?

Comment: could I know what your are going to achieve with the webview in the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell,  without viewing code, I believe you are looking for the `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths()`. Call it using `collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [NSIndexPath])` and then specify which you wish to reload. It would be more helpful to have additional information as to what you are trying to accomplish, as I could only infer this is what you were asking. Good luck!

Full Example

Create an NSIndexPath that points to the first cell (0), in the first section (0), then update that specific index path.

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)

collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [indexPath])
```

This will only reload the cell at your specified Index Path.

Comment: I ended up using collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [indexPath]) since I was adding new rows to my collection. 

collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [indexPath]) is apparently used for existing rows which have changed.